# tangent space clarification 

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I was just wondering why we don't define the tangent space of a smooth manifold at a point $p$ to be $\{p\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n}$, rather than using derivations, germs, or equivalence classes of curves? I just started learning the material, so maybe I should just keep on reading...

Comment: Among other things, that definition doesn't allow you to correctly describe the relationship between the tangent spaces of two nearby points (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle#Topology_and_smooth_structure). I also have no idea how you would give a coordinate-free definition of the derivative of a smooth map at a point this way.

Comment: Even for embedded manifolds in some $\mathbb{R}^m$, if we did, then any smooth manifolds would be parallelizable, i.e. the tangent bundle $TM = M \times \mathbb{R}^n$, which is false. You can take $M=S^2.$ See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem