# Fitting a non-linear curve in symmetric positive definite matrix manifold

Tags: statistics, differential-geometry, curves, machine-learning, covariance

I have a variable $x \in \mathbb{R}$. For some values of $x$, $\{x_1, ..., x_n\}$, I have measured a covariance matrix of the variable $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, conditional on these values of the variable $x$. That is, I have a set of covariance matrices $\{ \Sigma(x_1), ..., \Sigma(x_n) \}$ that belong to $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

From visual inspection, it is seen that these covariance matrices vary smoothly with the value of $x$, with each entry drawing a smooth curve.

The problem I have is that I want to interpolate between the observed covariances $\{ \Sigma(x_1), ..., \Sigma(x_n) \}$, to the covariances $\Sigma(x)$ at values of $x \in [x_1, x_n]$ not present in the dataset. I need the resulting interpolated matrices to also be covariance matrices (i.e. symmetric positive definite matrices, SPDM). For the interpolation, I want to take into account the form of the complex curve that the matrices $\Sigma(x)$ are seen to draw, and not just make an interpolation between adjacent pairs present in the dataset $\Sigma(x_k)$ and $\Sigma(x_{k+1})$.

This problem can be seen as a problem of fitting a non-linear curve to points on the SPDM manifold. This would guarantee that the resulting interpolated matrices are covariance matrices, and also the non-linear geometry of the manifold would be taken into account for the curve fitting. Note that this problem is different from just geodesic interpolation, which would not take into account the global shape of the curve drawn by the points in the SPDM manifold, but just interpolate between adjacent pairs $\Sigma(x_k)$ and $\Sigma(x_{k+1})$.

So, the question is if there are any ideas of how to fit a curve to some points in the symmetric positive definite matrices manifold. We can assume that the measured points are noiseless, or that they are noisy, any solution works.

**[Edit:]** After it being noted that the problem may not be clear, I edited the question to make it clear that geodesic interpolation is not what I am looking for. I also removed an incomplete/speculative idea from the initial post, since I found an answer that I posted below.

Comment: I think log-Euclidean operations would be the most sound since they actually characterize the manifold compared to simple element-wise operations. This seems to be a good reference and they do some interpolation here: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/mrm.20965

Comment: Thanks. However, in that paper (as in similar ones I was aware of), they just do geodesic interpolation between two points, analogous to linear interpolation in euclidean spaces. What I am looking for is a non-linear curve fitting in the manifold, so it is not the same as geodesic interpolation. For the curve-fitting I think that element-wise fitting will be necessary, although we can do it in a manifold-aware way. See if my answer below seems reasonable to you, where I think we'd apply element-wise regression in step 2).

Comment: "I would like to interpolate the matrices I observed for some values of $x$
 to covariance matrices in unobserved values of $x$." With no noise, this seems like it answers your question...

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I didn't specify the problem in the best way possible. But imagine that you have a function $y = x^2$ that you sample at $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$, with no noise. You want to interpolate a point $y(x)$ with $x \in (x_{k}, x_{k+1})$, such that $x = x_{k} t + x_{k+1} (1-t)$ with known $t$. I see what the paper proposes as analogous to taking $ y(x) = y(x_{k}) t + y(x_{k+1}) (1-t) $, but using a manifold geodesic. What I want to do is analogous to fitting a polynomial curve in this example, and using that to interpolate.

Comment: How would an exact interpolant not be a valid solution to your problem? It seems to me that there is some work to be done to actually figure out what problem you are trying to solve. Is your proposed curve solving some least square problem? If so, what metric? What space of curves are allowed?

Comment: Part of the answers are on the answer to the question below. Do you agree that in my example of $y(x) = x^2$ above, just taking the shortest path between two adjacent $x_{k}, x_{k+1}$ points isn't the best way to predict values of $y(x)$ for new $x$? I'm not sure how I can make it clearer than than that example that exact interpolation can be a suboptimal solution to the problem above of predicting the $\Sigma(x)$ for unobserved $x$'s, so I'd first want to know if that example is unclear/non-valid.

Comment: And to be more specific, the answers to your questions would be within step 2) in the answer below, which is a part I left unspecified in the answer because those are details that will be highly problem-specific and that can be modified or empirically explored. Elaborating on the answer below, one could for example use the Wasserstein metric to do steps 1) and 3) below. Step 2 which is on transformed data that is now on a vector space could use, for example, Gaussian Process regression with an L2 loss on that space.

Comment: If you do find the answer below reasonable, please consider upvoting, since people downvoted it because the original version lacked formulas, I think.

Comment: BTW. I edited the question in response to your comments, I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

We have an observed set of covariance matrices $\Sigma(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ parametrized by variable $x \in \mathbb{R}$, observed at a finite set of values of $x$, $\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}$. We want to fit a curve to these matrices, in order to approximate the value of $\Sigma(x)$ for values of $x$ not in our dataset.

The challenge is that we want our interpolated matrices to be covariance matrices, or in other words, to be points in the Symmetric Positive Definite Matrices (SPDM) manifold. If we just apply standard regression techniques (e.g. Gaussian Process Regression or Spline Regression), the interpolated values are not guaranteed to be in the SPDM manifold. Also, this approach would not take into account the geometry of the SPDM manifold to measure distances.

A way to approach this problem is described in this [tutorial](https://geomstats.github.io/notebooks/05_practical_methods__simple_machine_learning_on_tangent_spaces.html) of the differential geometry Python package [geomstats](https://geomstats.github.io/), and seems to be a standard approach in the literature.

In short, the approach involves 1) mapping our data points, which lay on the SPDM manifold, to a vector space, 2) apply the standard regression toolkit (which works just fine in a vector space) 3) do the inverse mapping, from the interpolations performed in the vector space, to the original manifold, obtaining the interpolated SPDM points.

For 1), we want a mapping into a vector space that respects as much as possible the geometry of the points in the manifold. For this, as described in the tutorial, we first compute the [Frechet mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_mean) of our datapoins $ \{ \Sigma(x_1), \Sigma(x_2), ..., \Sigma(x_n) \} $, which we call $\widehat{\Sigma}$. Then, we use the Logarithmic map (explained in section 5 [here](https://geomstats.github.io/notebooks/02_foundations__connection_riemannian_metric.html)) at point $\widehat{\Sigma}$, or $Log_{\widehat{\Sigma}}: \mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{T}_{\widehat{\Sigma}}\mathcal{M}$, to map all the points in our dataset to the tangent space of the manifold $\mathcal{M}$ at the Frechet mean (i.e. $\mathcal{T}_{\widehat{\Sigma}}\mathcal{M}$).

Naming $v(x) = Log_{\widehat{\Sigma}}(\Sigma(x))$, we now have a set of vectors $\{ v(x_1), v(x_2), ..., v(x_n) \}$ representing the dataset in the vector space. Of note, these vectors are in the space of symmetric matrices (as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3037846/proof-a-tangent-space-of-the-manifold-of-spd-matrices-is-the-set-of-symmetric-m)). We can now 2) apply the standard regression toolkit to this new vector dataset, such as spline regression, or whatever the user deems best for the problem. After applying the regression, we are able to interpolate $v(x)$ for any value of $x \in [x_1, x_n ]$.

Finally, 3) we take any $v(x)$ and apply the exponential map at the Frechet mean, or $Exp_{\widehat{\Sigma}}: \mathcal{T}_{\widehat{\Sigma}}\mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{M}$, to obtain the interpolated covariance matrix $\Sigma(x) = Exp_{\widehat{\Sigma}}(v(x))$.

Thus, the above delineates a strategy to do regression on covariance matrices, while respecting their geometry, and guaranteeing that the interpolated matrices are also covariance matrices. Although possibly intimidating for the non-expert the manifold-related tools mentioned above are available in the geomstats package linked above, and easy to use, as shown in the tutorial (I'm not affiliated with geomstats whatsoever).

**[Edit:]** I'm not sure why my previous answer in plain english got taken down, since it seemed to give a clear solution to the problem I had (I'm the poster of the question). I edited the answer to include mathematical notation, in case that was the thing moderators found lacking.